# What is the correct output of !(notThisDir) ? Copying all except one directory

Tags: bash

So as to copy all except one file: I generally use the `!(noThisFile)` expression (available with `shopt -s extglob`).

In the current case what I want to avoid is the `.git` directory . Astonishingly I have tried:

```
cp -r !(.git) my-target-dir
```

but it also copied entirely the content of the `../` directory

As a matter of fact, when I

```
echo !(.git)
```

The output starts with:

```
. .. myDir myDir2 myFile myFile2
```

I don't remember I had such issue while copying when using `!(notthisfile)`
And when I check with a file name, there are no `.` `..` in the output

- Is it correct that for `!(.avoidingDir)` my system should also return both `.` and `..` ?
- If it is correct, what should I do to circumvent the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually somewhat interesting, in that at least Bash 4.4 seems to expand to dotfiles too with that pattern, even if `dotglob` is not in effect. Probably the leading `.` in the pattern is enough to bring them in, even though it's inside a negation.

<strike>If that's right or not, you'll have to ask the Bash developers.</strike> It's probably not meant to do that, since in Bash 5.0 it doesn't. (But if `dotglob` is set, you still get all dotfiles, including `.` and `..` .)

To get all but `.git`, `.` and `..`, you could expand the pattern to explicitly ignore `.` and `..` too, i.e. `!(.git|.|..)`, or use `GLOBIGNORE` to hide `.` and `..`:

```
$ mkdir .git .dot dir
$ echo !(.git|.|..)
dir .dot
$ GLOBIGNORE=.:..
$ echo !(.git)
dir .dot
```

(Just setting `GLOBIGNORE` to any non-empty value ignores `.` and `..`, but also *enables* `dotglob`.)

Or if you don't want to see any dotfiles, make sure `dotglob` is disabled, and just use `*`, no need to explicitly exclude `.git` then:

```
$ unset GLOBIGNORE
$ shopt -u dotglob
$ echo *
dir
```

Zsh also doesn't pull in `.` and `..`, even with `globdots` set, either with the ksh-style `!(.git)`, or with Zsh's own `^.git` or `*~.git`.

Comment: @Isaac, hmm, with those test files, `unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -u dotglob; shopt -s extglob; echo !(.git)` did give me `. .. dir .dot`. But ah, that was with Bash 4.4, I see that's different in Bash 5.0.

Comment: @Isaac, hmmh. You're right about `extglob` needing to be set on a line of its own, of course, not that it mattered for the experiment. Anyway, I still get a different result with the two bashes: `bash4.4.12 +O dotglob -O extglob -c 'echo !(.git)'` gives `. .. dir .dot`; and `bash5.0.3 +O dotglob -O extglob -c 'echo !(.git)'` gives just `dir`. (with GLOBIGNORE unset, too)

Comment: @Isaac, I'm not sure if I'm missing something. As an aside, at least according to the manual, an empty `GLOBIGNORE` will not ignore `.` and `..`, it has to be set to some non-empty value.

Comment: @Isaac, ah sorry, I misread you there.

Comment: @Isaac, yeah, it's ok. Anyway, for what it's worth, and maybe not much, I do get `.` and `..` for `GLOBIGNORE=; echo .*`, and the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) seems to say it has to be "set and not null". But I'm not going to test this any further, it's late enough already.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: it depends.

A glob, any glob, will match dot-files if GLOBIGNORE is unset **and** the bash option dotglob is set:

```
$ mkdir test; cd test; touch .git .one .two file myfile; \
  mkdir .dir .new dir here

test $ ls -a 
.  ..  .dir  dir  here  .new  file  .git  myfile  .one  .two

test $ unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -s dotglob; echo *
.dir dir file .git here myfile .new .one .two

test $ unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -u dotglob; echo *
dir file here myfile

test $ unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -u dotglob; echo .*
. .. .dir .git .new .one .two
```

So, if dotglob is unset, dot-files are ignored. Unless explicitly included the `.*` above, for example.

Note that `.` and `..` must be matched explicitly even if `dotglob` is set.

#### About !(.git)

But yes, `!(.git)` (as anything with an starting dot) triggers the match of `.` and `..` as well as all dot-files.

```
shopt -u dotglob; echo !(.a); shopt -s dotglob; echo !(.a)
dir file here myfile
. .. .dir dir file .git here myfile .new .one .two
```

You can avoid the inclusion of `.` and `..` by setting GLOBIGNORE. Just remember that setting `GLOBIGNORE` also sets `dotglob`, and unsetting `GLOBIGNORE` also unsets `dotglob`.

```
test $ shopt -u dotglob; GLOBIGNORE="."; shopt -p dotglob; echo !(.a)
shopt -s dotglob
.dir dir file .git here myfile .new .one .two

test $ shopt -s dotglob; unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -p dotglob; echo !(.a)   
shopt -u dotglob
dir file here myfile
```

So, as a workaround, set GLOBIGNORE to `.:..` to avoid the expansion of `.` and `..`.